# How to input phone number in this 'xxx-xxx-xxxx' format in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want that when I enter numbers in `TextInput` field it will take as

`123-456-7890` this `format`, without installing any library.

Comment: this will lead you for what you wants https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-number-input

Answer (score 2):

You can convert data using regular expressions.

**Example**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput,View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { num: '' };
  }

  changeNum(num) {
    formatNum = num.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3');
    this.setState({
      num: formatNum
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"}}>
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, width:"80%"}}
        onChangeText={(num) => this.changeNum(num)}
        value={this.state.num}
        maxLength={12} 
        keyboardType={'numeric'}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answering. But here, when we entering 12+ digits in the TextIput then it is working otherwise it is not working. Please, could you fix it? Here is the [link](https://snack.expo.io/rJdgOo67H)

Comment: @AfifaKhan  It should be replaced differently by text length.

Comment: I use there `maxLength` with value 12 but not working. After taping same number keyword on 13th time then it is formatting in this `xxx-xxx-xxxx` format

Comment: You can change this `num.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3');`